# If construction in VBA

Tags: vba

Found these strings in code:

```
Dim lng As Long
...
If lng Then
...
End If
```

What does this condition mean? What values of `lng` would enter `If`? and what values would avoid it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lng` has to be anything other than 0 to enter the loop, and 0 (or `False`) to pass over it.

Slightly related: the `True` literal in VBA has a value of -1 when converted to an Integer or Long.